# Error: USB 1-1.1 string descriptor 0 read error -22

Tags: drivers, usb

I have been running Ubuntu 14.04 on my Acer Aspire One 756 quite happily for a while now.
However, every time I boot up my notebook, it displays the error "USB 1-1.1 string descriptor 0 read error -22" for some time before it continues booting.
What can I do to solve it?

```
Dmesg | grep -i usb
```

provides the following info, containing the error as well:

```
dmesg | grep -i usb
[    0.470834] ACPI: bus type USB registered
[    0.470858] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.470870] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.470904] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    1.691475] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    1.691658] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.706928] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    1.706987] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.706990] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.706992] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.706995] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-37-generic ehci_hcd
[    1.706997] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1a.0
[    1.707186] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.707449] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    1.723005] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    1.723118] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.723122] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.723125] usb usb2: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.723127] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-37-generic ehci_hcd
[    1.723130] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.0
[    1.723379] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.723537] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    1.723558] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    2.018985] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    2.151334] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0024
[    2.151345] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    2.151732] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.262898] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    2.395069] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0024
[    2.395080] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    2.395527] hub 2-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.466817] usb 1-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[    2.561291] usb 1-1.1: string descriptor 0 read error: -22
[    2.561308] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0489, idProduct=e04e
[    2.561314] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    2.630783] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[    2.779691] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=04f2, idProduct=b336
[    2.779697] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.779700] usb 1-1.3: Product: HD WebCam
[    2.779703] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: HD WebCam
[   14.088233] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[   14.090780] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath3k
[   14.807864] input: HD WebCam as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/input/input13
[   14.808096] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[   14.808099] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[  242.008518] usb 1-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[  242.100420] usb 1-1.1: device firmware changed
[  242.172321] usb 1-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[  244.244853] usb 1-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[  244.318558] usb 1-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[  244.420076] usb 1-1.1: string descriptor 0 read error: -22
[  244.420092] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0489, idProduct=e04e
[  244.420098] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  244.799816] usb 1-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 5
[  245.001765] usb 1-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[  245.661045] usb 1-1.1: string descriptor 0 read error: -22
[  245.661055] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0489, idProduct=e04e
[  245.661059] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
```

Comment: What device is attached to this port? `lsusb` should tell you.

Comment: @the_Seppi lsusb shows the following information: 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b336 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0489:e04e Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Answer (score 1):

Every USB device has different descriptors with information about the device, among them you can find "device descriptors", "configuration descriptors", "string descriptors".

Your error was triggers by
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0489:e04e Foxconn / Hon Hai

This device can not read the string descriptor
String descriptors provide human readable information and are optional.

This is not the reason of your boot latency.

Further reading: http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb5.shtml#StringDescriptors